# Restricting Developers access to Production in DevOps?

Tags: compliance, devops

In a devops context, how do you approach seperating development from production environments (which is an ISO27001:2022 Annex A control) ? Is granting developers access to production a necessary evil in today's agile devolpment context ? Or is the security requirement to "prohibit devs from accessing prod" obsolete ?

Answer (score 1):

The principles remain the same. One of the most important ones is [The principle of Least Privilege and Separation of Duties](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Secure_Product_Design_Cheat_Sheet.html).

DevOps does not mean that literally every developer needs access to the PROD environment. Furthermore, Ops or SysOps part is pretty complex. In reality, in many cases (though not always) people do either Ops/SysOps tasks or Dev tasks. For instance, if there are only 3 people working on software, the chances are that 2 or even 3 of them need access to PROD to be able to do their tasks. But if there are 600 developers, only a small part of them would really need access to the PROD.

Give PROD permissions to as little developers as possible. If deployment and other processes like refreshing certificates are automated, why would many developers need access to PROD?

Even for support tasks there should be well established processes. First, any issues should be reproduced on some non-PROD environment. If reproducible, then there is no need for PROD access. If not reproducible, you can give access to PROD logs, but for a *limited* period of time, like 4 hours or 8 hours, and prolongate only if needed and as long as needed.

> is the security requirement to "prohibit devs from accessing prod" obsolete

It is very simplified definition. There has never been such a rule. Instead, give access only to person that needs it for *particular* task, only when they needed, and for a limited period of time.

And even some tasks are closely related to particular persons, it does not mean they should obtain more permissions. Again, see the link above:

> Separation of duties ... is a system of checks and balances that ensures that no single individual has control over all aspects of a transaction. This is done by assigning different tasks to different people, so that no one person has control over the entire process.

You can even rotate some permissions e.g. every 6 months. Important is that no one has too much power, even if it has price that some tasks take a bit more time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the objective of restricting access. This is usually on the lines of reducing the risk of inappropriate or malicious software being promoted to the production environment.

In Devops the main distinction where this is done is at code level. Consider:

1. Branch protection, requiring 1+ peer reviewers for critical branches. Feature branches are considered dev, main/master branches to be considered production. See the separatation there?
2. Change testing (automatic or manual). Tests must be committed and reviewed in step 1 in case of automatic tests. If tests fail, code does not make it to stable branches.
3. In a semi automated delivery context, controls may also apply to have the build manually tested on a staging environment and perhaps reviewed and promoted to prod, by a different person than the author(s) of the change.

Other measures would supplement the original objectives such as SAST tools like SonarCloud/Qube which would block the change from moving forward if a medium or high vulnerability is found.

In a 27001 context make sure that these processes are documented and approved. You can find a lot of information on controls specific to Devops, in the Cobit for Devops (2022) document.